# Passing information from resolver to post-resolution middleware

Tags: elixir, graphql, absinthe

Im trying to pass from information from my resolver function to my middleware such that I can set a cookie in the response.

The use-case is I want to generate an Oauth2 authorization link which allows the client to begin an Oauth2 flow with a third party. I want to generate a "state" object which I can set as a cookie in the response.

I've tried calling

```
   %{resolution | context: state}
```

within the resolver but unfortunately that doesn't seem to pass that state down.

Here is a simplified example of my resolver function

```
def get_oauth_link(_parent, _args, resolution) do
    state = random_string(10)

    part_one = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize"
    part_two = "?client_id=XXX"
    part_three = "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/login/callback"
    part_four = "&state=" <> state
    part_five = "&scope=user:email"

    url = part_one <> part_two <> part_three <> part_four <> part_five

    # try to add the state to the resolution to 
    %{resolution | context: state}

    {:ok, url}
  end
```

And then in my schema

```
    @desc "Get oauth link"
    field :oauthlink non_null(:string) do
      resolve(&Resolvers.OauthResolver.get_oauth_link/3)

      # middleware after resolution to set a cookie with the provided state
      middleware fn resolution, _ ->
        # Here i want to extract the state generated in
        # the resolver and add to the context 
        IO.inspect(resolution, label: "Inside resolution")
      end
    end
```

Im expecting to be able to set the cookie in the "absinthe_before_send" method as documented here: https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe_plug/Absinthe.Plug.html#module-before-send

Whats the best way of doing this? The approach above seems intuitive to me but the state is not available in the post-resolution middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the resolution in a resolver function.

You can, however, change the resolution in the middleware. That's what middlewares are for. The post resolver middleware resolution will have a `value` field which contains result from the resolver function (without the `:ok` or `:error` atom).

What you can do is return both `state` and `url` from your resolver function, then in your post resolution middleware, extract the state from the resolution `value` field and reset the resolution `value` to the url. Like this:

```
   def get_oauth_link(_parent, _args, resolution) do
    state = random_string(10)

    part_one = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize"
    part_two = "?client_id=XXX"
    part_three = "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/login/callback"
    part_four = "&state=" <> state
    part_five = "&scope=user:email"

    url = part_one <> part_two <> part_three <> part_four <> part_five

    {:ok, %{url: url, state: state}} # return state and url
  end


   field :oauthlink, non_null(:string) do
      resolve(&Resolvers.OauthResolver.get_oauth_link/3)
      middleware fn %{value: %{state: state, url: url}=resolution, _ ->        
        resolution
        |> Map.put(:context, state) # set context using state
        |> Map.put(:value, url) # reset value to url
      end
   end
```

Comment: Answered almost on the same time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change resolution like you are doing.

To be honest, I can't understand why you can't use only the middleware for setting or not it. Why you can't generate only that on the middleware?

However, I can see a way of doing that.

```
@desc "Return api version"
field :version, :version_payload do
  resolve(fn _, _ -> {:ok, %{version: OnCallAPI.version(), other: "Marcos"}} end)

  middleware fn resolution, _ ->
    # Here i want to extract the state generated in
    # the resolver and add to the context
    IO.inspect(resolution, label: "Inside resolution")
  end
end
```

If you check the console, you sill see the `other` on the `values`. Like this:

```
...
private: %{},
root_value: %{},
schema: OnCallAPIWeb.Schema,
source: %{},
state: :resolved,
value: %{other: "Marcos", version: "0.30.0-rc"}
```